# MFC Reading text file word by word

Tags: c++, mfc

When I press button, I want to read text file word by word. I succeeded reading line by line using this code. I think `scanf_s()` is good for this code to read text file word by word, but I don't know how to apply it on here.

```
void CFileloadView::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CFileDialog dlg(TRUE, _T("*.txt"), NULL, OFN_FILEMUSTEXIST | OFN_OVERWRITEPROMPT,
             _T("TXT Files(*.txt)|*.txt|"), NULL);
    if (dlg.DoModal() == IDOK)
    {
        CStdioFile rFile;
        CString strBufferLine;
        int count = 0;

        int num;

        if (!rFile.Open(dlg.GetPathName(), CFile::modeRead))
        {
            MessageBox(_T("Can't OpenFile!"), _T("Warning"), MB_OK | MB_ICONHAND);
            return;
        }

        while (rFile.ReadString(strBufferLine)) 
        {
            //fscanf(rFile, "%d", &num);

            count++;
            m_list2.AddString(strBufferLine);
            strBufferLine.Replace(("\r"), ("")); 

            if (strBufferLine.GetAt(0) == '#')
                continue; 
        }
        rFile.Close();
    }
}
```

Anyone can see what's the problem?

Comment: Note that the last `if` statement does nothing: the `while` loop will `continue` regardless.

Answer (score 0):

After reading the line from `CStdioFile`, use `CString::Tokenize` to parse a `CString` as follows:

```
while (rFile.ReadString(strBufferLine))
{ 
    int pos = 0;
    CString word = strBufferLine.Tokenize(" ", pos);
    while (!word.IsEmpty())
    {
        num = atoi(word.GetString());
        word = strBufferLine.Tokenize(" ", pos);
    }
}
```

`scanf` reads console input, or redirected input. `fscanf` can be used to read a file which was opened with `fopen`, both these methods are C.

Use `std::ifstream` to open the file in C++, use `>>` operator to read word by word. For example

```
std::string str;
std::ifstream fin("file.txt");
while (fin >> str)
{
    ...
}
```